# Connection failure in talend

Tags: talend

I am a newbie to talend tool and I am trying to create a job for which I had established a DB connection It was working fine before but since I restarted talend I had to import the existing project into new workspace and now the connection doesnt happen I get

```
Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:179)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1034)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:300)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.utils.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:293)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm.checkConnection(DatabaseForm.java:2008)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm.access$39(DatabaseForm.java:1933)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$23.widgetSelected(DatabaseForm.java:2261)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.metadata.CreateConnectionAction.doRun(CreateConnectionAction.java:207)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.AContextualAction$2.run(AContextualAction.java:608)
      at org.talend.repository.RepositoryWorkUnit.executeRun(RepositoryWorkUnit.java:93)
      at org.talend.core.repository.model.AbstractRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(AbstractRepositoryFactory.java:237)
      at org.talend.repository.localprovider.model.LocalRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(LocalRepositoryFactory.java:3197)
      at org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:1979)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.AContextualAction.run(AContextualAction.java:617)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
      at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:145)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:41)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:170)
      ... 48 more
  Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
      at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
      ... 54 more
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
      at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
      ... 59 more
```

Help me resolve this issue. I googled a lot but not able to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database outside of Talend from your machine? Try SQlDeveloper/Toad or whatever IDE you use for checking the connection. The error simply points to the fact that the hostname you specified for DB is not reachable

Comment: @Incognito Yes your right I am unable to connect from my sql developer as well. thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting might simply be pointing to the fact that the database is not accessible from your machine, as in the hostname cannot be reached.

To verify the same, try connecting to the database using any IDe of your choice - SQLDeveloper/Toad or simply SQL*plus.

Answer (score 0):

Error is pointing about unavailability of database for your machine. To check status of any service including databases simply execute command **services.msc** in run menu, and you can enable service manually if it is disabled by choosing **Start service** option. And you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your connection details, Sometimes there might be a chance to have irrelevant values passing to the connection details to your components like passing wrong context variables or values. 
Or sometimes there might be a chance that your output or input component is not connected with the component from which you are passing the context.

**Check:**Try to print the connection details you are passing and see whether they are appropriate or not. If not try to find out for the possible reason by checking the above situations.